# Grunt Uglify returning different minified code from multiple developers

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

When I uglify my code my machine produces a different minified version of javascript than another developer.  Both of our minified code is correct but it is slightly different.

For Example:

```
-            }) : (a.visible = !1, a.videoCss = b > d ? "hideLeft" : "hideRight");
+            }) : (a.visible = !1, b > d ? a.videoCss = "hideLeft" : a.videoCss = "hideRight");
```

Verified that we are both using the same version of Grunt Uglify:   "version": "0.6.0".

Comment: Had similar problems like this before, try updating node, npm, grunt and plugins all to the same version. Ideally maintained via a package.json file

Comment: What version of `uglify-js` do you have installed as `grunt-contrib-uglify`'s dependency? The Grunt plugin [only requires](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/v0.6.0/package.json#L33) that it be a `2.x` version that's at least `2.4.0`, so maybe one of you has a newer `uglify-js` that's made some changes to these kinds of assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ran into this problem before.  Remember that your package.json file will specify what version of `grunt-contrib-uglify` to use; but `grunt-contrib-uglify` has *it's own* dependencies.  It's possible that you have inconsistent versions of `uglify-js`.  To check this, in the root of the project (where the package.json file is) type:

> npm list | grep 'uglify'

The output should look like:

```
├─┬ grunt-contrib-uglify@0.9.1
│ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.4.23
│ │ ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
```

A technique for locking down the sub dependencies of your top level dependencies is by using [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).  This will generate a file called `npm-shrinkwrap.json` which recursively scans your node_modules directory and defines dependencies and sub-dependencies and their specific versions.  In your case, the command will probably look like

> npm shrinkwrap --dev

Now, when someone else runs npm install - they should get the same versions for each dependency and its sub-dependencies.